# MS Fakes: Shims with given input

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

Suppose that I have a method

```
public void SomeFunction (int a) 
{
    return AnotherFunction (a + 1);
}
```

Is there a way to shim AnotherFunction with specific parameters? I am thinking of something like:

```
using (ShimContext.Create())
{
    ShimMyClass.AnotherFunctionInt = (3) => 34; // return 34 if the given value is 3
    ShimMyClass.AnotherFunctionInt = (4) => 44; // return 44 if the given value is 4
    ShimMyClass.AnotherFunctionInt = (a) => 22; // default value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add code to your override instead of returning a hardcoded value.  Something like

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleTest()
    {
        TestUnitTestClass tutClass = new TestUnitTestClass();
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            ShimTestUnitTestClass shimClass = new ShimTestUnitTestClass(tutClass);
            shimClass.AnotherFunctionInt32 = (val) =>
            {
                if (val == 3)
                    return 34;

                if (val == 4)
                    return 44;

                return 22;
            };

            int curInt = tutClass.AnotherFunction(3);
            Console.WriteLine(curInt);
        }
    }
```